# Will Ashe's Frost Shot proc Iceborn Gauntlet and Rylai's Passive?

Tags: league-of-legends

As the title says, will her Q proc them upon firing arrows? I've heard yes and no, so I wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the following information for the [League wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ashe/Ability_Details), Frost Shot will not proc Iceborn Gauntlets since it is a toggle ability. [Iceborn Gauntlet](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Iceborn_Gauntlet) shares the same passive effect as Sheen so it should function in the same way. You will need an actual spell cast such as Volley to get the effect rather than just toggling Frost Shot on or off.
.

> - Frost Shot does not proc Rylai's slow when applied with auto-attacks.
> - Toggling Frost Shot does not count as a spell cast for the purposes of  Force Pulse,  Sap Magic or items like Sheen and Tear of the
>   Goddess (although Tear of the Goddess will be charged every time you
>   shoot a frosted arrow due to its unique passive).

If you get the Iceborn Gauntlet effect to proc from a different spell cast, then it will apply to your next basic attack regardless if you have frost shot on. Here is an example of someone using Iceborn Gauntlet on Ashe by spamming volley to get the Iceborn Gauntlet effect:

A teamfight starts at 35:44 that shows the volley spam to proc Iceborn Gauntlet. You can see the same thing in a bit calmer setting when he is farming minions earlier.

Comment: So, you are saying the Spellblade passive will proc upon firing arrows? Or not at all?

Comment: @Jonny I added a youtube video to show what I mean a bit better. Basically you have to spam volley to get the iceborn effect but once you do (and you have the blue glow on your hands) then you can apply it on your next attack no matter if frost shot is on or off

Comment: Rylai's has no practical use on champions that have slows built into their kits. It creates a redundancy that could have been replaced with something more beneficial to the champion.

Comment: @Ravekner I'd agree, I would not make a habit of building Rylai's or Iceborn Gauntlets on Ashe.